# AngularJS view just render correctly after screen interaction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an Angular App with two controllers that updates two models every time a new info is sent by server. To clarify, the same info must be updated in the same view, but two different scopes. In the Header, present in every page of the application, using "NavigationController" and in the myQueue.html page, using QueueController.

**myQueue.html**

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        <div class="navigation" ng-controller="NavigationController">
            <nav class="tab-bar">
                <section class="left-small">
                    <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle bh-logo-top"><span></span></a>
                </section>
                <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
                    <ul id="top-menu" class="clearfix">
                        <li id="msg-icon" ng-click="verMensagens();"><span></span></li>
                        <li id="fav-icon" ng-click="verFavoritos();"><span></span></li>
                        <li id="fila-icon" ng-click="visualizarFila(estaEmFila);"><span>{{queuePosition}}</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <section class="right-small">
                    <a href="#/success/{{user.user_id}}" id="bh-search-icon"><span></span></a>
                </section>
            </nav>
            <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
                <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                    <li><label id="aside-header"></label></li>


            <li><a>{{user.nome_frequentador}}</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="verMensagens()">Mensagens</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="verFavoritos()">Favoritos</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="ficarInvisivel()" ng-show="visible">Invis&iacute;vel</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="ficarVisivel()" ng-show="invisible">Vis&iacute;vel</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="verUsuariosBloqueados()">Usu&aacute;rios Bloqueados</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="sugerir()">Sugest&atilde;o</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="logout()">Sair</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </div>      
    <section id="main-container-minha-fila">
        <div class="row" id="estabelecimento-info">
            <div class="columns small-3 left" id="estabelecimento-logo">
                <img src="http://homologa.boadahora.com.br{{fila.logo}}"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="columns small-9" id="fila-info">
                <h6>{{fila.estabelecimento.nome}}</h6>
                <h6>{{fila.nome_fila}}</h6>
                <strong>Tempo de espera: </strong><span>{{fila.tempo_estimado}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="user-list-container row">
            <button id="deixar-fila" class="button alert radius" ng-click="deixarFila()">Deixar Fila</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="minha-entrada">
            <h6 id="nome-entrada-frequentador">{{fila.frequentador}}</h6>
            <div id="minha-entrada-info">
                <strong>Posi&ccedil;&atilde;o: </strong><em id="minha-posicao">{{position}}</em><br/>
                <strong>Hor&aacute;rio de Entrada: </strong><em>{{fila.horario_entrada}}</em>
                <br/>
                <span ng-show="fila.respondeu">
                    <strong>Token: </strong><em>{{token}}</em>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
</div>
```

**NavigationController**

```
(function updateQueue(){
        $http.post(url,dataQuery{
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            if(data.posicao){
                if($scope.queuePosition!== data.position){
                    $scope.estaEmFila = true;
                    $scope.fila = data.fila;
                    $scope.$emit('positionChanged', data.posicao);
                }
                $scope.queuePosition= data.position;
                $timeout(updateQueue, 5000);
            }else{
                $scope.queuePosition= 0;
                $scope.estaEmFila = false;
            }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(data)
        });
    })();
```

**QueueController**

```
$scope.$on('positionChanged', function(e, data){
        $scope.position = data;
    })
```

Question is is: I need the user position in queue to be updated every time, and the best place for this to happen is in the header, and then, if the user is in his queue screen, it'll be automatically updated because NavigationController emits positionChanged event. Everything is working fine, the model gets updated, however...

[image]

QueueController recieves the event and update the model correctly, NavigationController, from where the event is sent, also updates the model correctly(As you can see in Chrome inspector), but the header doesn't render it properly. Funny thing is that if the browser tab goes to background (Browser minimized, changed screen,etc. etc.) OR if I click/touch somewhere in the screen, everything renders perfectly, as you can see below(Only changed tabs and then got back).

[image]

I have no idea of what could be the cause of this, can anyone help me?

Comment: You should use $rootScope.$broadcast, and $rootScope.$on

Comment: @ZackArgyle any scope can use `$.on` to listen to `rootScope` broadcast

Comment: Actually, that's not the problem. The problem is that the view only gets rendered when user interacts with screen.